# Applicative Instance of Pair Data Type in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to implement this pair data type as an applicative functor but I am told that 'a' is not in scope. I thought already stated what 'a' was in the instance declaration.

```
data Pair a b = Pair a b deriving (Show)

instance Functor (Pair a) where 
    fmap f (Pair a b) = Pair a (f b)

instance Applicative (Pair a) where
    
    pure x = Pair a x
    Pair a f <*> Pair a' x = Pair (a + a') (f x)
```

Comment: `a` is a type variable; it's not something you can pass to the *data* constructor `Pair` as an argument. The `Pair` constructed  by `pure x` must contain some concrete value of *type* `a`. Where will you get that value if you don't know which type `a` is? (Hint: this suggest that there should be some constraint on `a`: `instance (??? a) => Applicative Pair a) where ...`

Comment: `fmap` is OK because the `a` in `fmap f (Pair a b) = ...` is *not* the type variable `a`; it's a name set by the pattern `Pair a b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` is a type variable, not something you can use in the definition of `pure`. `pure` needs some way of getting a *value* of type `a` to pair with `x`. There are a few ways you could do that:

1. A function of type `b -> a` that you could apply to `x`.
2. A function of type `() -> a` that you could apply to `()`.
3. Some predefined value of type `a`.

The `Applicative` instance of `(,) a` takes the third approach, by requiring that `a` have a `Monoid` instance so that you can define `pure` in terms of `mempty`.

```
instance Monoid a => Applicative (Pair a) where
    pure x = Pair mempty x
    Pair a f <*> Pair a' x = Pair (a <> a') (f x)
```

In your definition, you assumed that `(+)` is defined for the `a` values, which means you are missing a `Num` constraint, but also that you could simply use `0` in your definition of `pure`.

```
instance Num a => Applicative (Pair a) where
    pure x = Pair 0 x
    Pair a f <*> Pair a' x = Pair (a + a') (f x)
```

Comment: Right! I completely forgot about the constraint. It makes sense that I can't just assume that mappend, mconcat and mempty are known. Thanks :)

Comment: (To be fair, neither of the first two options is feasible since the necessary family of functions don't exist, though a typeclass providing them could be defined and used as a constraint on `a`, just as `Monoid` is a typeclass that allows the use of option 3.)

Comment: Why suggest `() -> a` as a solution? I'm sure you know this is isomorphic to `a`.

Comment: I'm not sure :) I had functions on the brain, and I might have been planning to mention the isomorphism as a segue from functions to values.

Answer (score 0):

You can also derive it via the [new `Generically1`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html#t:Generically1) applied to [`Sum a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Sum)

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DerivingStrategies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DerivingVia        #-}

import GHC.Generics (Generic1, Generically1(..))
import Data.Monoid  (Sum(..))

data Pair a b = Pair a b
  deriving
  stock (Show, Generic1)

  deriving (Functor, Applicative)
  via Generically1 (Pair (Sum a))
```